# checking check box code not working if($('#primayins').attr('checked')) { $("#tx_nm0x0_pricingplan").show(); } else { }

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

code not working

```
if($('#primayins').attr('checked')) 
{    
   $("#tx_nm0x0_pricingplan").val(1); 
} 
else 
{   
   $("#tx_nm0x0_pricingplan").val(2);
}
```

every time it is getting false.......................

Comment: `$('#primayins)` should be `$('#primayins')`

Comment: You have an obvious syntax error in the code you posted. You're missing a `'`.

Comment: eventhough iam using $('#primayins') its not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) method instead :-

```
if ($('#primayins').prop('checked')) {
    $("#tx_nm0x0_pricingplan").val(1);
} else {
    $("#tx_nm0x0_pricingplan").val(2);
}
```

Also you have a typo. Missing the single quotes in the below code

```
if($('#primayins).attr('checked')) 
             ___^___
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a typo in your selector - a missing closing apostrophe. However, you can use the `is()` function to check the state of an element. Try this:

```
var pricingPlan = $('#primayins').is(':checked') ? 1 : 2;
$("#tx_nm0x0_pricingplan").val(pricingPlan);
```

Answer (score 1):

`$('#primayins)` is not quoted properly.

Use this:

```
$('#primayins')
```